# what is blocking my main thread?

Tags: python, twisted

I have a fairly large twisted-based application. Somewhere there is a bit of code that does too much computation in the main thread, causing latency spikes. I want to put it into a background thread, but I have to find the culprit first.

Has twisted any tools to help me track down where the main thread is held up?

Twisted should be able to notice if the thread doesn't return within a few milliseconds and then help me figure out what is keeping the thread busy. For example by dumping the stacktrace of the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geoff Greer has [a tool called `twisted_hang`](https://github.com/ggreer/twisted_hang) that can show you where twisted processes are hanging.

Comment: Hah! Exactly what I was looking for. I've hacked together something very similar yesterday (using a background thread and sys._current_frames instead of signals, though). Good to see that I'm not the only one that failed to do this without dirty hacks :)

Answer (score 1):

Running:

```
twistd -n -y hello_world.tac --profile=pstats_obj --profiler=cprofile --savestats
```

Outputs from terminal:

```
bob@squids:~/Desktop/toy_problems/twisted$ twistd -n -y hello_world.tac --profile=pstats_obj --profiler=cprofile --savestats
2015-08-17 06:52:23-0500 [-] Log opened.
2015-08-17 06:52:23-0500 [-] twistd 14.0.2 (/usr/bin/python 2.7.9) starting up.
2015-08-17 06:52:23-0500 [-] reactor class: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor.
2015-08-17 06:52:23-0500 [-] Site starting on 8000
2015-08-17 06:52:23-0500 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site instance at 0x7f81e54002d8>
2015-08-17 06:52:35-0500 [HTTPChannel,0,127.0.0.1] "127.0.0.1" - - [17/Aug/2015:11:52:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 53 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"
2015-08-17 06:52:35-0500 [HTTPChannel,0,127.0.0.1] "127.0.0.1" - - [17/Aug/2015:11:52:35 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 64 "http://localhost:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"
^C2015-08-17 06:52:40-0500 [-] Received SIGINT, shutting down.
2015-08-17 06:52:40-0500 [-] (TCP Port 8000 Closed)
2015-08-17 06:52:40-0500 [-] Stopping factory <twisted.web.server.Site instance at 0x7f81e54002d8>
2015-08-17 06:52:40-0500 [-] Main loop terminated.
2015-08-17 06:52:40-0500 [-] Server Shut Down.
bob@squids:~/Desktop/toy_problems/twisted$
```

And then:

```
import pstats
s = pstats.Stats('pstats_obj')
s.sort_stats('time')
```

Or you can run without `--savestats`: `twistd -n -y hello_world.tac --profile=pstats_obj --profiler=cprofile`

```
     508 function calls (501 primitive calls) in 0.036 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(abs)
    4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(acquire)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(add)
   15    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(append)
   12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(callable)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(clear)
    6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(copy)
    8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(fcntl)
    3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(fileno)
    4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(flush)
    4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(fromtimestamp)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(get)
    9    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(get_ident)
    5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(getattr)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(getsignal)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(gmtime)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(hasattr)
    3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(heappop)
    4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(heappush)
   21    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(isinstance)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(iter)
    4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(join)
   18    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(len)
    4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(map)
    5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(max)
    5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(min)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(pipe)
    5    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.001 :0(poll)
   16    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(pop)
    4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(range)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(read)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(register)
    4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(release)

# from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.application import service, internet
from twisted.web import static, server
from twisted.web.resource import Resource

class Hello(Resource):

    def getChild(self, name, request):
        return self

    def render_GET(self, request):
        return '<html>Hello, GET world! I am located at %r. </html>' \
                % (request.prepath)

def getWebService():
    """
    Return a service suitable for creating an application object.
    """
    site = server.Site(Hello())
    # site = server.Site(Hello())
    # reactor.listenTCP(8000, site)
    # reactor.run()
    return internet.TCPServer(8000, site)

# this is the core part of any tac file, the creation of the root-level
# application object
application = service.Application("Hello application")

# attach the service to its parent application
service = getWebService()
service.setServiceParent(application)
```

Here is the "hello_word.tac":

```
# from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import static, server
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.application import service, internet

class Hello(Resource):

    def getChild(self, name, request):
        return self

    def render_GET(self, request):
        return '<html>Hello, GET world! I am located at %r. </html>' \
                % (request.prepath)

def getWebService():
    """
    Return a service suitable for creating an application object.

    This service is a simple web server that serves files on port 8080 from
    underneath the current working directory.
    """
    site = server.Site(Hello())

    return internet.TCPServer(8000, site)

# this is the core part of any tac file, the creation of the root-level
# application object
application = service.Application("Hello application")

# attach the service to its parent application
service = getWebService()
service.setServiceParent(application)
```

Once profiled, then you could add a decorator to add a hook of some sort (line by line) to profile the calls that are taking up a lot of time.

Comment: I've tried profiling in the past and didn't manage to find the bottleneck with it. I haven't investigated in depth, but it seems that the async nature of twisted doesn't lend it self well to profiling, expecially @inlineCallbacks caused some strange results if I remember correctly. I didn't run it with twistd, though.